# How to replace first and last character

Tags: c#

i want to replace @param but i want to know first and last charcter in @param

```
//declare variable
string source = "select * from table where tablename like '%@param%'";
string replacestring = "'admin'";

//check before replace
if(check before @param have % or last @param have %)
{
    source.Replace("'", string.Empty);
    source.Replace("@param", replacestring);
}
else
{
    source.Replace("@param", replacestring);
}
```

Comment: Use StartsWith and EndsWith

Comment: What is the expected output in both case.?

Comment: this is vulnerable to an sql injection attack, keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String.StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [String.EndsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netframework-4.7.2) as:

```
string str = "%param%";
if (str.StartsWith("%") || str.StartsWith("%"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: i cant use starwith because variable "string source" is input by user and dynamic

Comment: @Cleo Do you mean you need to check if `source.Contains("%param%")`?

Comment: yess, thx bro i think is worked  --> source.Contains("%param%")

Answer (score 0):

In *general case* you want *parsing*: what if you have

```
select 'bla-bla-bla %@DoNotChangeThis% string' -- string within query
  from MyTable
```

query? However, you can try *regular expressions* if you can guarantee that the queries are simple enough:

```
  string source = "select * from table where tablename like '%@param%'";

  // Let's generalize solution: 
  //   1. Get all @param@ matches
  //   2. Change them according their names
  string result = Regex.Replace(
      source,
    @"(?<=%)@[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?=%)",
      match => 
        match.Value == "@param" ? "admin"        // @param to "admin" 
                                : match.Value);  // unknown - do not change

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  select * from table where tablename like '%admin%'
```